# How to use PrimaryKeyRelatedField to update categories on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The Django Rest Framework has a [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) which lists ID's on my `many-to-many` relationship with categories...

```
class CatalogueItemsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='catalogue_item_detail')
    name = serializers.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=60)
    categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

I would like to override the `create()` get a lot of posted ID's (traditionally DRF wants me to send URL's) on the categories field.

JSON POST:

```
{
"name": "test",
"categories": [1,2]
}
```

Serializer Create:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    categories = validated_data.pop('categories', None)
    print(categories) # This shows and empty/None even when ID are posted!
```

The issue I have is `categories` will be empty above, I assume because `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is set to `read_only=True` but this **HAS** to be true on according to DRF.

My question is... How to use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with `validated_data.pop` to get a list of ID's I submitted?

I could use `self.context.get("request").data['categories']` but this is nasty and requires me to turn it into a list + other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue I found a solution that allows `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to be read/writeable. Just add `queryset`

```
categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

It will still filter on the correct relationship which is a bit confusing.