# Correct Django serializer implementation for many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two django models that are related with a many to many field:

```
class Member(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  date_of_birth = models.DateField()
  bio = models.TextField()


class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  author= models.CharField(max_length=255)
  description = models.TextField()
  read_by = models.ManyToManyField(to=Member, related_name='books_read')
```

The serializers for these models are:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.Model):
  id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  user_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'date_of_birth', 'bio']


class BookSerializer(serializers.Model):
  id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'author', 'bio']
```

I want to create an endpoint to be able to add a book to a member. The only way I could write a serializer for it was:

```
class BookIdSerializer(serializers.Model):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['id']

  def update(self, **kwargs):
    # logic to add book with passed id to the authenticated user's member profile
```

This however feels very wrong for two obvious reasons:

1 - There is an entire serializer object just to receive a book id
2 - It is not even generic because it performs a very specific function of adding a book with passed book id to a member

I am sure there is a better way of doing this. Kindly guide me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PrimaryKeyRelatedField:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.Model):
  id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  user_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
  books = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Book.objects.all())
  class Meta:
    model = Member
    fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'date_of_birth', 'bio', 'books']
```

This will place the related books in an array, and you can edit that array to add and remove books, allowing adding or removing many at a time.

See [How to use PrimaryKeyRelatedField to update categories on a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801739/how-to-use-primarykeyrelatedfield-to-update-categories-on-a-many-to-many-relatio) for a related question/answer.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem I discovered with this approach is that all books belonging to a user are returned in the books field when a get request is made. I think a separate endpoint just to post and get these books is required in the form of `{url}/members/{id}/books_read` and that is why I was writing a `BookIdSerializer` but again that seems to be a very bad approach

Comment: Just mark the field as write_only if you don't want it to be sent on get requests.

Comment: But I do want to retrieve it with the mentioned `{url}/members/{id}/books_read` url